# Replacing a string from one class to another with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a string from class to another. I have a H1 tag on the page and the idea is that when it's visible the user can place some text into a text box to override the H1 tag (header class) and the corresponding menu item (thing class). Currently I can get the H1 tag to replace but the I can't figure out how to replace the string in the menu. All of my experiments have lead to all of the strings being replaced.

```
<div class='thing'>One</div>
<div class='thing'>Two</div>
<div class='thing'>Three</div>
<div class='thing'>Four</div>
<div class='thing'>Five</div>

<h1 class='header'>One</h1>
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" value="">
```

Some of my JavaScript for replacing the H1 tag:

```
var userInput = $('#textbox').val();
$('.header:visible').text(userInput);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$('.thing').eq(3).text( $('#textbox').val() )`

Comment: Could you show your full code?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through menu items and search your header value:

```
var userInput = $('#textbox').val(),
    headerValue = $('h1').text();
$('.thing').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == headerValue) {
       $(this).val(userInput);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using merezha's code however I replaced .val with .text

```
var userInput = $('#textbox').val(),
    headerValue = $('h1').text();
$('.thing').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == headerValue) {
       $(this).text(userInput);
    }   
});
```

Thanks everyone!